# How to get string address by coordinates?

Tags: google-maps

How to get string address by coordinates? I am using gmaps.js  3rd party API. Is there someone how was working with it? I want to get string addresses, and I know coordinates.

**UPD.** Actually I know about google maps standart tutorials, the question is how to pick up the data using gmaps.js. I know for sure that this data can be taken.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it's supported by gmaps.js, but basically you are searching for ["reverse geocoding"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse)

EDIT:
Unfortunately there is no "direct" support in gmaps.js for (reverse) geocoding, but you can still use google geocoding in gmap.js (in a mixed way):

```
var opt = {
    lat : 40.714224,
    lng : -73.961452,
    callback : function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            console.log(results[1].formatted_address);
        }
    }
}

GMaps.geocode(opt);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the help at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/  OR https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/ 
These links are google tutorials for google geocoding API.